# Stop broken NFS mounts from locking a directory in solaris 11.3?

Tags: mount, solaris, nfs, zfs, shared-folders

Data from my nfs server:

```
zfs set share=name=opt_media,path=/opt/media,prot=nfs,sec=sys,root=iphostclent,public,rw=* rpool/media
```

Data from my nfs client:

```
mount -F nfs -o bg,soft,retry=5,timeo=5 iphostserver:/opt/media /opt/media
```

I use options:

```
bg

soft

retry=5

timeo=5
```

more info:

```
nfsstat -m

/opt/media from iphostserver:/opt/media

Flags:         vers=4,proto=tcp,sec=sys,soft,printed,intr,link,symlink,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,retrans=5,timeo=5

Attr cache:    acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60
```

but, if I turn off my nfs server, in my nfs client the /opt/media/ directory is blocked.

add:

The problem are the applications, for example df -h it freezes, or an app that depends on the /opt/media/ directory, also it freezes, and this is because the nfs client is trying to reconnect infinitely, therefore the parameters bg, soft, retry = 5, timeo = 5 to stop retry, but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the /opt/media/ directory is blocked"?  You turned the NFS server off - the directory certainly isn't going to be accessible.

Comment: yes, but the problem are the applications, for example df -h it freezes, or an app that depends on the / opt / media directory, also it freezes, and this is because the nfs client is trying to reconnect infinitely, therefore the parameters bg, soft, retry = 5, timeo = 5 to stop retry, but it does not work.

Comment: What exact OS version is your NFS client system running?

Comment: My SO is Solaris 11.3 (server and client nfs), my nfs's version is 4, and this is a man page of nfs in solaris. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0211/6m6nc670v/index.html

Comment: Can you interrupt applications such as a hung `ls` with `CTRL-C`?

Comment: yes, `ctrl + c` works without problems. The problem are the applications, for example if a script works with `if [ -d "/opt/media/ ]` it freezes, instead of ruling out that the directory does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the mount_nfs(1M) man page:
>
> hard | soft
>
> Continue to retry requests until the server responds (hard)  or
>
> give  up and return an error (soft). The default value is hard.
>
> **Note that NFSv4 clients do not support soft mounts.**

The solution is mount with:

```
mount -F nfs -o vers=3,soft,timeo=10 iphostserver:/opt/media /opt/media
```

now we see the properties:

```
nfsstat -m

/opt/media from iphostserver:/opt/media

Flags:         vers=3,proto=tcp,sec=sys,soft,intr,link,symlink,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,retrans=5,timeo=10

Attr cache:    acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60
```

Comment: Nice to know Oracle has continued the hallowed Sun tradition of burying important details in a single sentence on a man page somewhere.  At least this one's actually on the `mount_nfs` man page.